# At grocery stores, alcoholic drinks are in the liquor section and non-alcoholic drinks are in the _______ section

Tags: word-request

What would you call this "non-alcoholic" section at a grocery store? It contains soft drinks, fruit juice, bottled water, energy drinks and similar stuff. I suppose "non-alcoholic beverages section" could work, but it sounds clunky and totally wrong. Any better suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[british-english](/questions/tagged/british-english)

I would call it the "non-alcoholic drinks section".  There is no need for a less "clunky" name.

There is really no limit on how a supermarket might arrange its aisles.  My local has separate aisles for wine and cider compared to beer and spirits. Then coke etc are grouped with "party food", and is separate from bottled water, and also separate from fruit juice. So no "liquor section"  (liquor in that sense is American English anyway.)

So the only way to talk about sections of a supermarket is to describe the food in the section, clunky or not.

Comment: I think *non-alcoholic drinks section* is a very clunky name and sounds quite awkward  in my view Maybe if you could the US equivalent of *soft drinks* that would make the answer more useful. In  the US they'd probably call it the "pop" or "soda aisle".

Comment: In much of the US, liquor laws either forbid or tightly restrict the sale of alcohol in grocery stores. So this question is often irrelevant.

Comment: I've tagged the answer.  The whole deal with US laws the continuing fallout from prohibition is beyond my ken.  The point is merely that you can name a section by the type of food.  If a food sells "pop" then it is the "pop section"   BrE tends not to use "pop" in that sense much (except as deliberately dated speech)

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for the broad spectrum name they're likely to hang on a sign above the aisle in a supermarket, in the UK, these would tend to be grouped as 'Fizzy & Soft Drinks', or just soft drinks.

They also don't tend to call alcoholic drinks directly by that name, they'll use 'Beers, Wines & Spirits" instead. Low & zero alcohol beers and wines will be in here too.

Just to note: Brits don't use the term 'liquor', that's very American.